# Bootstrap navbar-brand jump below the navbar menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, navbar

[image]i have a bootstrap navbar-brand that jumps below (moves down) respect its original position when the window is resized (smaller). That's because the navbar menu (the three horizontal bars)on the right when resizing the windows collapse with the navbar-brand.. The logo inside the navbar-brand is in the svg format.. How can I adapt the navbar-brand so that it doesn't jump below?

Menu html code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button> <!-- end button navbar -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="loghi/logo.svg"></a>
    </div><!-- end navbar-header -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="chi_siamo.php">Chi Siamo</a></li>
        <li><a href="listini.php">Listini</a></li>
        <li><a href="contatti.php">Contatti</a></li>
        <li><a href="disclaimer.php">Disclaimer</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- end collapse navbar-collapse -->
  </div> <!-- end container menu -->
</nav> <!-- end navbar -->
<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="container">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/img_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/img_2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/img_3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          </div> <!-- end item -->
      </div> <!-- end carousel-inner -->
    </div> <!-- end carousel-example generic -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
<!-- /carousel -->
```

this is the css code (a part of it):

```
/****************/
/* BOOTSTRAP CSS*/
/****************/

 .navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  /* (80px - button height 34px) / 2 = 23px */
  margin-top: 23px;
  padding: 9px 10px !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    /* (80px - line-height of 27px) / 2 = 26.5px */
    padding-top: 26.5px;
    padding-bottom: 26.5px;
    line-height: 27px;
  }
}


.navbar-brand img {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right a{
 font-size: 14px;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a:hover {
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: #eb0c0c;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Edit: As you can see from the photos, the first one and the second one are ok but the third is not..

Comment: Make the `navbar-brand` smaller with media query. Get the width where it breaks and add a media query to make it smaller.

Comment: thanks! it worked, I used this simple code to solve the problem:

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .navbar-brand { width: 70%; }
}

Comment: I posted this as the answer so you can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only happens on a smaller screen you can use a media query so it will change the width/height of the image on smaller screens.

(Code you provided that worked)

```
@media (max-width: 420px) {
 .navbar-brand { 
    width: 70%; 
 } 
}
```